# Beamer Title Image above authors in Dresden theme

Tags: beamer, titles

Using `beamer`, I'm trying to add an image to the title page. Currently I'm doing this by using the command as an argument for the `\date` command, since it would be left blank anyway. Now, the image shows up beneath the authors. I don't want to leave the `\author` part blank and add the names manually, because the authors also show up in the footnote. I'm using the `Dresden` theme. I've tried a bunch but I'm not getting it to look right. How do I add the title image above the authors, with the authors still showing up in the footnote?

Currently, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Auth1 \and Auth2 \and Auth3}
\date{\includegraphics[width=117pt,height=175pt,keepaspectratio]{image.png}}

\begin{document}
    \frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the most possibilities to achieve any layout you like, you can just define your own title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
        \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=117pt,height=175pt,keepaspectratio]{pic}
    \end{center}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
        \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \endgroup
    \vfill
}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Auth1 \and Auth2 \and Auth3}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]